# os.copystat fails on panfs when u+w not set on src, causing pip install to fail; where to report a bug?

Tags: python, git, pip, shutil, panfs

I'm doing `pip install .`, where the current working directory is on a [panfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panasas#PanFS) filesystem.  When `pip` tries to copy the directory tree, including the files in `.git`, it fails due to what is ultimately a failure in `os.setxattr`:

```
$ pip install .
Processing /home/users/gholl/checkouts/pyatmlab
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/users/gholl/venv/stable-3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/users/gholl/venv/stable-3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 280, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/home/users/gholl/venv/stable-3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 317, in prepare_files
    functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
  File "/home/users/gholl/venv/stable-3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 304, in _walk_req_to_install
    more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
  File "/home/users/gholl/venv/stable-3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 469, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session)
  File "/home/users/gholl/venv/stable-3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 814, in unpack_url
    unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir)
  File "/home/users/gholl/venv/stable-3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 699, in unpack_file_url
    shutil.copytree(link_path, location, symlinks=True)
  File "/home/users/gholl/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 343, in copytree
    raise Error(errors)
shutil.Error: [('/home/users/gholl/checkouts/pyatmlab/.git/objects/pack/pack-c1449559ec4287b3830efe2913608dddf2f21391.pack', '/tmp/pip-6lrnz9vs-build/.git/objects/pack/pack-c1449559ec4287b3830efe2913608dddf2f21391.pack', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/pip-6lrnz9vs-build/.git/objects/pack/pack-c1449559ec4287b3830efe2913608dddf2f21391.pack'"), ('/home/users/gholl/checkouts/pyatmlab/.git/objects/pack/pack-c1449559ec4287b3830efe2913608dddf2f21391.idx', '/tmp/pip-6lrnz9vs-build/.git/objects/pack/pack-c1449559ec4287b3830efe2913608dddf2f21391.idx', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/pip-6lrnz9vs-build/.git/objects/pack/pack-c1449559ec4287b3830efe2913608dddf2f21391.idx'")]
```

Some deeper digging shows the error originates in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/users/gholl/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 329, in copytree
    copy_function(srcname, dstname)
  File "/home/users/gholl/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 246, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/home/users/gholl/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 213, in copystat
    _copyxattr(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow)
  File "/home/users/gholl/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 153, in _copyxattr
    os.setxattr(dst, name, value, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/pip-y3dw8fwa-build/.git/objects/pack/pack-c1449559ec4287b3830efe2913608dddf2f21391.pack'  File "/home/users/gholl/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 329, in copytree
```

...and can be reproduced by:

```
In [55]: shutil.copystat("/home/users/gholl/checkouts/pyatmlab/.git/objects/pack/pack-c1449559ec4287b3830efe2913608dddf2f21391.pack", "/tmp/fubar")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-139c9fc77184> in <module>()
----> 1 shutil.copystat("/home/users/gholl/checkouts/pyatmlab/.git/objects/pack/pack-c1449559ec4287b3830efe2913608dddf2f21391.pack", "/tmp/fubar")

/home/users/gholl/lib/python3.4/shutil.py in copystat(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    211             else:
    212                 raise
--> 213     _copyxattr(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow)
    214
    215 def copy(src, dst, *, follow_symlinks=True):

/home/users/gholl/lib/python3.4/shutil.py in _copyxattr(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    151             try:
    152                 value = os.getxattr(src, name, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
--> 153                 os.setxattr(dst, name, value, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
    154             except OSError as e:
    155                 if e.errno not in (errno.EPERM, errno.ENOTSUP, errno.ENODATA):

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/fubar'
```

This occurs for any source file where the user write bit is not set.

Now, who should handle this?  Is this a bug in `pip`, `shutil.copytree`, `shutil.copystat`, `setxattr`, `panfs`, or none of the above?

Reported as [issue 24538](https://bugs.python.org/issue24538).  See also [this question on Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212905/15654).